Can you make an authenticator between Node.js and tampermonkey?
I made a tampermonkey script and I need to add an authenticator APP for it. I'm doing it seperately then integrating it into the script afterwards. Is there any way tampermonkey can interact with a discord bot and send it requests to authenticate the user who's using the script, like: Entering the discord username of the user and making tampermonkey send a direct request to the discord bot, which receives it and returns with true or false? I already know tampermonkey can interact with a discord bot, but not if it can receive and send requests from it.
I tried using a specific header and hosting a bot server, but it just appeared on localhost. I tried using glitch to fix this but I wasn't able to host it 24/7, skill issue on my side. Any other way to do this?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I didn’t see that your question had anything to do with Java, so I removed that tag. JavaScript and Java are vastly different programming languages.
